# how to get HttpPostAttribute in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda

I whant to get only Post methods in code for dynamic Roles.but this code return Get and Post methods.

How to get **Only Post Methods** in this Code?:

```
  Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        var contradistinction = asm.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .SelectMany(type =>
                type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Controller = x.DeclaringType?.Name,
                Action = x.Name,
                Area = x.DeclaringType?.CustomAttributes.Where(c => c.AttributeType == typeof(AreaAttribute))
            });

        var oo = contradistinction.ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: You already know how to get custom attributes, so filter by methods that only have HttpPostAttribute. But this will only find methods properly attributed and not those that are convention based or explicitly configured via endpoint routing

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: I would discourage you from using that method. If you want to implement dynamic roles (e.g. for authorization/routing), i would recommend using custom action filters. You will have access to an `ActionContext` which gives you better access to the action method, controller etc, while you still have access to all the DI services. Care to describe further what you are trying to do?